Why is memcpy performance from heap to shared memory so poor?
Original question
I tested memcpy performance from heap to heap and from heap to shared memory (shm_open). The test codes are as follows:
// shm_msg.hpp
#ifndef _SHM_MSG_HPP_
#define _SHM_MSG_HPP_

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <array>
#include <stdint.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 100 * 1024 * 1024 /* Maximum size */

typedef struct shmbuf
{
    uint32_t a;
    double b;
    std::array<uint8_t, BUF_SIZE> data;
    uint64_t c;
} shmbuf;

#endif // !_SHM_MSG_HPP_

// shm_openWriter.cpp
#include "shm_msg.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>
#include <chrono>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    /* Create shared memory object and set its size to the size
       of our structure. */

    int fd = shm_open("SHM_1", O_CREAT | O_EXCL | O_RDWR, 0600);
    if (fd == -1)
    {
        perror("shm_open");
    }
    size_t size = sizeof(shmbuf);
    if (ftruncate(fd, size) == -1)
    {
        perror("ftruncate");
    }

    /* Map the object into the caller's address space. */

    shmbuf *shmp = (shmbuf *)mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                                  MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    if (shmp == MAP_FAILED)
    {
        perror("mmap");
    }

    /* Copy data into the shared memory object. */
    std::vector<uint8_t> vec(BUF_SIZE, 0x56);
    vec[100] = 0x89;
    shmp->a = 5;
    shmp->b = 2.5;
    shmp->c = 100L;
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point tp1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::memcpy(shmp->data.data(), vec.data(), BUF_SIZE);
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point tp2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    printf("data[100] = 0x%X\n", shmp->data[100]);
    std::cout << "a = " << shmp->a << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b = " << shmp->b << std::endl;
    std::cout << "c = " << shmp->c << std::endl;
    std::cout << "memcpy time from heap to SHM = " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(tp2 - tp1).count() / 1e6 << " ms." << std::endl;

    std::vector<uint8_t> vec2(BUF_SIZE);
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point tp3 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    // std::memcpy(shmp->data.data(), vec.data(), BUF_SIZE); // wrong line
    std::memcpy(vec2.data(), vec.data(), BUF_SIZE); // new line based on @RaymondChen's answer.
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point tp4 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << "memcpy time from heap to heap = " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(tp4 - tp3).count() / 1e6 << " ms." << std::endl;

    shm_unlink("SHM_1");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

compile and run the test:
g++ shm_openWriter.cpp -o shm_openWriter
./shm_openWriter

output:
data[100] = 0x89
a = 5
b = 2.5
c = 100
memcpy time from heap to SHM = 239.019 ms.
memcpy time from heap to heap = 14.3007 ms.

It can be seen from the output that memcpy from heap to shared memory is 17x slower than memcpy from heap to heap.
Why is memcpy from heap to shared memory so slow? Is there any way to improve the performance of memcpy?
Additional information 1
Based on @PepijnKramer's comment.
typedef struct shm_buf2
{
    shmbuf buf1;
    shmbuf buf2;
} shm_buf2;

shm_buf2 *shmp = (shm_buf2 *)mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);

std::vector<uint8_t> vec(BUF_SIZE, 0x56);
std::memcpy(shmp->buf1.data.data(), vec.data(), BUF_SIZE);

while (true)
{
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point tp1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::memcpy(shmp->buf2.data.data(), shmp->buf1.data.data(), BUF_SIZE);
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point tp2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << "memcpy time from SHM to SHM = " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(tp2 - tp1).count() / 1e6 << " ms." << std::endl;
}

compile and run:
g++ shm_openWriter.cpp -o shm_openWriter -O2
./shm_openWriter

output:
memcpy time from SHM to SHM = 197.639 ms.
memcpy time from SHM to SHM = 15.1024 ms.
memcpy time from SHM to SHM = 11.276 ms.
memcpy time from SHM to SHM = 21.0165 ms.
memcpy time from SHM to SHM = 17.694 ms.
...

The first memcpy is still slow and the others are fast.
But this performance is from SHM to SHM. So the performance from heap to SHM is still worse. Am I right?
Additional information 2
Based on @TobySpeight's answer.
shmbuf *shmp = (shmbuf *)mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_POPULATE, fd, 0); // add MAP_POPULATE to the flag

output:
$ ./shm_openWriter
data[100] = 0x89
a = 5
b = 2.5
c = 100
memcpy time from heap to SHM = 35.6653 ms.
memcpy time from heap to heap = 28.604 ms.

It shows a good memcpy performance from heap to SHM.

Your benchmark is invalid: you're not running an optimized build. What happens if you specify -O2 or -O3? - or any of these?

While @Dai proposal to optimize is a valid one, I would venture this copy goes through kernel, which slows things down a lot

@SeverinPappadeux It shouldn't. The caller has it mapped into his own address space. The hardware does all the work here.

Turn on optimizations.  Any timings without those is meaningless.  debug code is basically slow on purpose so it can be easily debugged.

The second memcpy is a copy from heap to shared memory: std::memcpy(shmp->data.data(), vec.data(), BUF_SIZE); (Not std::memcpy(vec2->data(), vec.data(), BUF_SIZE);) So all you're seeing is demand paging and cache warming effects.

If you do want to see the performance without paging effects. Make a loop that writes a value to all the shared_memory before you start looping. This should load all the pages in memory allowing you to only measure the effect of copying.

Soory about the second memcpy. The second memcpy should be std::memcpy(vec2.data(), vec.data(), BUF_SIZE);

You're probably faulting-in the pages as you go.  A fairer comparison would include MAP_POPULATE in the flags so that that overhead isn't included in the timings.
